# Android: How to update just one column of multiple records using contentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

How can I update just one specific column of multiple records using content resolver?

```
update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] selectionArgs)
```

Does above function requires that I rewrite all the values of each record in the object of contentValues? When I used this function with just one value like:

```
ContentValues value = new ContentValues();      
value.put (Voicemails.IS_READ, 1 );//mark as read

int iRowsUpdated=contentResolver.update(uri, value, null, null);
```

Then I got exception "Cannot update URI: content://com.android.voicemail/voicemail?...Bulk update not supported", which is may be because "where" is set to null;

A tutorial mentioned that "To batch update a group of records in to Content provider, call ContentResolver.update() method with the columns and values to change."

But I am not able to do this....I still don't know how will I update just one column of all the records, basically I need to mark read voicemails as read.